# Action Script 3. Assign Movie Clips to other Movie Clips

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip

So I'm creating game where will be shown world map with active countries as buttons and in top of screen should randomly pop-up product which should be assigned to specific country. Idea of game is that player should answer from which country this product Is, If answer correct should pop-up other product with assigned country.

So I have to create each country and products as MovieClips, just how to assign to each products correct country? If country clicked It should check If products correct.

I need to put all countries to one array and products to other array? Just I'm confused how to make that checking.

```
package 
{
    Import Object1;
    Import Object2;
    //all objects...
    Import Canada;
    //all countries...

    public class MapGame extends MovieClip
    {
    private var object1:Object1;
    private var object2:Object2;
    private var object3:Object3;
    private var object4:Object4;
    private var object5:Object5;
    //etc.....

    private var canada:Canada;
    private var lithuania:Lithuania;
    private var uk:UK;
    private var italy:Italy;
    //etc.....

        private function CreateMap()
        {
            //Here should be code to add countries as buttons
        }
        private function SpawnProduct()
        {
            //Here should be code to spawn random Object
        }
        private function CheckProducts()
        {
            // Here should be checking If products correct.
        }
```

Also should be ability to assign multiple products to one country.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you.

Firstly let's create two Object's.

```
private var _countries:Object = {};
private var _objects:Object = {};
```

`_countries` assigns an objects to the country. Example:

`_countries[USA] = [object1, object2, object3]`;

So, USA contains three objects.

Same for the object:

`_objects[object1] = [USA, Italy, UK]`;

Next. This is a function that assigns an objects to the country and vice versa.

```
public function assignCountryAndObject(country:MovieClip, object:MovieClip):void
{
    if (_countries[country] is Array && _countries[country].indexOf(object) == -1)
        _countries[country].push(object);
    else
        _countries[country] = [object];

    if (_objects[object] is Array && _objects[object].indexOf(country) == -1)
        _objects[object].push(country);
    else
        _objects[object] = [country];
}
```

So you can call this method this way:

```
assignCountryAndObject(country1, obj3);
assignCountryAndObject(country2, obj2);
assignCountryAndObject(country2, obj4);
assignCountryAndObject(country2, obj2);
assignCountryAndObject(country3, obj4);
assignCountryAndObject(country3, obj1);
assignCountryAndObject(country3, obj2);
```

Next two functions are used to get all countries of an object or all objects of the country.

```
public function getCountriesOfObject(object:MovieClip):Array
{
    return _objects[object];
}

public function getObjectsOfCountry(country:MovieClip):Array
{
    return _countries[country];
}
```

For checking you can use next functions:

This function checks is object belongs to the country:

```
public function isObjectBelongsCountry(object:MovieClip, country:MovieClip):Boolean
{
    return _objects[object].indexOf(country) != -1;
}
```

This function checks is country belongs to an object:

```
public function isCountryBelongsObject(country:MovieClip, object:MovieClip):Boolean
{
    return _countries[country].indexOf(object) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using one array of items with all necessary information about countries and their products. Each element of that array should hold country name and array of products associated with that country. This is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        //Array that holds a country name and the array of products associated woth that country 
        //(each item is an instance of Item.as)
        private var allItems:Array;

        public function Main() 
        {
            this.allItems = new Array();

            //Create all items
            var item1:Item = new Item("Italy", ["Pizza", "Pasta"]);
            var item2:Item = new Item("Lithuania", ["Šaltibarsčiai"]);

            //Push those items into main allItems array
            this.allItems.push(item1, item2);

            //This traces all information in allItems array
            for(var i:int = 0; i < allItems.length; i++)
            {
                trace("Country:", allItems[i].country + ", " + "Products:", allItems[i].products);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Item.as class:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Item
    {
        public var country:String;
        public var products:Array;

        public function Item(country:String, products:Array) 
        {
            this.country = country;
            this.products = products;
        }
    }
}
```

I should also add that country and products doesn't necessarily have to be String's. They can be anything you want, like say MovieClips.

Linkėjimai :)